# Spring Roo File Upload

Tags: spring, file, file-upload, spring-roo

Hy everyone!

Im trying to implement file upload with Spring roo. The files path will be persisted in the database, and the file will be saved on the file system.
According to informations found on the spring dveloper board, i modified the input.tagx and create.tagx files.(info: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-442)
input.tagx:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"             xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<jsp:directive.attribute name="id" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The identifier for this tag (do not change!)" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="field" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The field exposed from the form backing object" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="label" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="The label used for this field, will default to a message bundle if not supplied" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="labelCode" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Key for label message bundle if label is not supplied" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="required" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Indicates if this field is required (default false)" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="disabled" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify if this field should be enabled" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="validationRegex" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify regular expression to be used for the validation of the input contents" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="validationMessageCode" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the message (message property code) to be displayed if the regular expression validation fails" />
<jsp:directive.attribute name="validationMessage" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the message to be displayed if the regular expression validation fails" />
```

```
<c:if test="${empty render or render}"
   <c:when test="${disableFormBinding}">
   <input id="_${field}_id" name="${field}" type="${type}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
<!-- currently (spring 3.0.3), form:input doesn't support type attribute -->
<!-- <form:input id="_${field}_id" path="${field}" disabled="${disabled}"/> -->
<input id="_${field}_id" name="${field}" type="${type}"/>
<br/>
<form:errors cssClass="errors" id="_${field}_error_id" path="${field}"/>
</c:otherwise>    
    <c:if test="${empty disabled}">
      <c:set value="false" var="disabled" />
    </c:if>

<c:if test="${empty label}">
  <c:if test="${empty labelCode}">
    <c:set var="labelCode" value="${fn:substringAfter(id,'_')}" />
  </c:if>


    <spring:message code="label_${fn:toLowerCase(labelCode)}" var="label" htmlEscape="false" />
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${empty validationMessage}">
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty validationMessageCode}">
          <spring:message arguments="${fn:escapeXml(label)}" code="field_invalid" var="field_invalid" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <spring:message arguments="${fn:escapeXml(label)}" code="${validationMessageCode}" var="field_invalid" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </c:if>

    <c:if test="${empty required}">
      <c:set value="false" var="required" />
    </c:if>

    <c:set var="sec_field">
      <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true" >${field}</spring:escapeBody>
    </c:set>

    <div id="_${fn:escapeXml(id)}_id">
      <label for="_${sec_field}_id">
        <c:out value="${fn:escapeXml(label)}" />
        :
      </label>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${disableFormBinding}">
          <input id="_${sec_field}_id" name="${sec_field}" type="${fn:escapeXml(type)}" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${type eq 'password'}">
              <form:password id="_${sec_field}_id" path="${sec_field}" disabled="${disabled}" />
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
              <form:input id="_${sec_field}_id" path="${sec_field}" disabled="${disabled}" />
            </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
          <br />
          <form:errors cssClass="errors" id="_${sec_field}_error_id" path="${sec_field}" />
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${required}">
          <spring:message code="field_required" var="field_required" htmlEscape="false" />
          <spring:message argumentSeparator="," arguments="${label},(${field_required})" code="field_simple_validation" var="field_validation" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <spring:message argumentSeparator="," arguments="${label}, " code="field_simple_validation" var="field_validation" htmlEscape="false" />
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
      <c:set var="sec_field_validation">
        <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${field_validation}</spring:escapeBody>
      </c:set>
      <c:set var="sec_field_invalid">
        <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true" htmlEscape="true">${field_invalid}</spring:escapeBody>
      </c:set>
      <c:set var="sec_field_required">
        <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${field_required}</spring:escapeBody>
      </c:set>
      <c:set var="sec_validation_regex" value="" />
      <c:if test="${!empty validationRegex}">
        <c:set var="sec_validation_regex" value="regExp : '${validationRegex}', " />
      </c:if>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : '_${sec_field}_id', widgetType : 'dijit.form.ValidationTextBox', widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: '${sec_field_validation}', invalidMessage: '${sec_field_invalid}', required : ${required}, ${sec_validation_regex} missingMessage : '${sec_field_required}' }})); 
      </script>
    </div>
    <br />
  </c:if>
</jsp:root>
```

create.tagx:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
  <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <jsp:directive.attribute name="id" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The identifier for this tag (do not change!)"/>
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="modelAttribute" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="The name of the model attribute for form binding"/>
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="path" type="java.lang.String" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" description="Specify the relative URL path (wit leading /)" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="compositePkField" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="The field name of the composite primary key (only used if a composite PK is present in the form backing object)" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="multipart" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Indicate if this is a multipart form (default: false)" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="label" type="java.lang.String" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="The label used for this object, will default to a message bundle if not supplied"/>
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="render" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Indicate if the contents of this tag and all enclosed tags should be rendered (default 'true')" />
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="openPane" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="false" rtexprvalue="true" description="Control if the title pane is opened or closed by default (default: true)"/>
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="z" type="java.lang.String" required="false" description="Used for checking if element has been modified (to recalculate simply provide empty string value)"/>
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="enctype" type="java.lang.String" required="false" description="Used to set the enctype, e.g. multipart/form-data for file upload support. "/>
  <c:if test="${empty render or render}">
    <c:if test="${empty label}">
      <spring:message code="label_${fn:toLowerCase(fn:substringAfter(id,'_'))}" var="label" htmlEscape="false" />
    </c:if>

    <!--<c:set var="enctype" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/> -->
    <form:form action="${form_url}" method="POST" modelAttribute="${modelAttribute}" enctype="${enctype}">
    </form:form>
    <c:if test="${multipart}">
      <c:set var="enctype" value="multipart/form-data"/>
    </c:if>
    <spring:message arguments="${label}" code="entity_create" var="title_msg" htmlEscape="false" />
    <util:panel id="${id}" title="${title_msg}" openPane="${openPane}">
      <spring:url value="${path}" var="form_url"/>
      <c:set var="jsCall" value=""/>
      <c:if test="${not empty compositePkField}">
        <c:set var="jsCall" value="encodePk()" />
      </c:if>
      <form:form action="${form_url}" method="POST" modelAttribute="${modelAttribute}" enctype="${enctype}" onsubmit="${jsCall}">
        <form:errors cssClass="errors" delimiter="&lt;p/&gt;"/>
        <c:if test="${not empty compositePkField}">
          <form:hidden id="_${fn:escapeXml(compositePkField)}_id" path="${fn:escapeXml(compositePkField)}" />
          <script type="text/javascript">
          <![CDATA[
            dojo.require("dojox.encoding.base64");
            function encodePk() {
              var obj = new Object();
              dojo.query("input[name^=\"${compositePkField}.\"]").forEach(function(node, index, nodelist){
                obj[node.name.substring('${compositePkField}'.length + 1)] = node.value;
              });
              var json = dojo.toJson(obj);
              var tokArr = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tokArr.push(json.charCodeAt(i));
              }
              var encoded = dojox.encoding.base64.encode(tokArr);
              dojo.byId('_${fn:escapeXml(compositePkField)}_id').value = encoded;
            }
          ]]>
          </script>
        </c:if>
        <jsp:doBody />
        <div class="submit" id="${fn:escapeXml(id)}_submit">
          <spring:message code="button_save" var="save_button" htmlEscape="false" />
          <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'proceed', event:'onclick'}));</script>
          <input id="proceed" type="submit" value="${fn:escapeXml(save_button)}"/>
        </div>
      </form:form>
    </util:panel>
  </c:if>
</jsp:root>
```

My problem is i get the fallowing error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Illegal use of &lt;when&gt;-style tag without &lt;choose&gt; as its direct parent
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.WhenTagSupport.doStartTag(WhenTagSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.input_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(input_tagx.java:519)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.input_tagx.doTag(input_tagx.java:325)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pphotoes.create_jspx._jspx_meth_field_005finput_005f0(create_jspx.java:172)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pphotoes.create_jspx.access$2(create_jspx.java:157)
```

What am i doing wrong? (My controller and entity files are good i think, if needed i can post them)

Thx for any help.
cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, you need to have a `<c:choose>` as a direct parent tag before the `<c:when>` tag - possibly in the following first few lines of your `input.tagx` file. Additionally, the `<c:if>` tag is not closed properly.

```
<c:if test="${empty render or render}"
    <c:when test="${disableFormBinding}">
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Its a very obvious answer but helped me focus my debugging effort. I ended up having a <choose> tag instead of <c:choose>